# Raindrop splash/splatter dynamics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, erosion

I'm interested in the physics/dynamics of a drop of water (2-5 mm dia) dropped from a height (terminal velocity is the limit) on smooth hydrophobic surfaces. Specifically the largest diameter of splattered droplets, height, number of droplets, etc.

I have seen references to this with soil splatter and erosion from raindrops but I'm more interest in the dynamics of the drop itself.

Comment: So, what specifically is the question here?

Comment: @Fred  I guess it's a reference request .

Comment: Maybe https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-21370-5 ?